# Running Gulp from inside a container without bashing in

Tags: docker, gulp, docker-compose, dockerfile

I’m running a Drupal 8 project in Docker the only problem I’m having is getting Gulp to run in the theme directory.

I’ve got it installed and am able to bash into the container, move to the theme directory then run Gulp but would ideally like to run it straight from the host command line, for example using the exec command. The reason for wanting to run it like this is purely to simplicity & each developer being able to use the terminal environment they're used to.

When I try this command

`docker-compose exec web --workdir="/var/www/html/web/themes/material_admin" gulp --version`

I just get an error stating

`OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"--workdir=/var/www/html/web/themes/material_admin\": stat --workdir=/var/www/html/web/themes/material_admin: no such file or directory": unknown": unknown`

but when I bash into the container using `docker-compose exec web bash` I can cd into that directory so it must exist.

Comment: Usually you'd put commands that "build the project", like `gulp`, into a Dockerfile, and developers would run `docker build` as part of their pre-commit testing.  (But I bet if you put `--workdir` _before_ the container name `web` it'll work better.)

Comment: @DavidMaze You're right putting it before worked a treat, should really have spotted that myself =/. My goal is to have Gulp running inside the container as the developer is working to create the CSS files from SASS files and having it run from the container reduces the requirements on the host machine. If I understand you correctly you were saying it's normally only run at the pre-commit stage? Not just running in the background?

Comment: Also as a note to anyone trying this if you get a error about the API version it's because the docker-compose version is not high enough. Can't remember which version is required but changed it to 3.7